# How to receive data in a vector<uint8_t> from a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, embedded, lwip

I am working on a project with the library LWIP on my ESP32. In this project, I have a TCP communication between my ESP32 and some hardware via a socket.

After connecting the socket and establishing the communication, I am trying to receive some byte data sent to the ESP32 through the socket. I am using `std::vector<uint8_t> recvVec(1200)` to store the data I receive from the socket. To do so, I am calling the recv method of lwip as such :

```
int messRcv = recv(sock, recvVec.data(), recvVec.size(), 0);
```

If I don't somehow end the receiving process, the socket will never stop receiving data.

The data/packets I receive differ in sizes. The first is 332 bytes, the second 446, and after these most of the packets are 1024 bytes. If I leave the communication going for a while, I end up receiving packets of 4 bytes. Also, when I am printing these packets by printing each byte in my vector, as it's unsigned value since I can't print bytes, I get an output of numbers I don't expect.

The packet I expect back is an XML type packet with UTF-8 encoding. This packet begins with the character `<` whose decimal value is 60. So I expect a packet of bytes begining with the unsigned decimal value of 60. Instead, when I print the first packet I receive with size of 332 bytes, I get back the values 60 60 60 0 1 60 60 60 ... and so on. The packets that follow also repeat one decimal value over and over.

Is this an encryption problem, or a problem with the way I receive the data? Is there a way to know when to stop receiving packets?

Comment: How to know when to stop receiving packets is the real question. The socket will not tell you, but the data that is in the packet might.

Comment: TCP is a *streaming* protocol, all data is just a stream of bytes. There are no "packets" or "messages". All such have to be implemented in the application protocol layer above TCP.

Comment: From what you have described there is no problem with how you are reading the data (although since you only quoted two lines of code it's not possible to be certain). Instead the main issue is how to interpret the first packet you receive. Hard to help you with that, since we don't know anything about who or what is sending the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You will have to parse the data as it arrives.  Rather than receiving a vector, a FIFO (pipe, queue) would be more appropriate.  You parse the data stream and can if necessary place it in a vector until you have the complete application specific structure sought.  You cannot expect the vector to be "magically" aware of the content.